# SignalR Client-Server communication WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, signalr

The idea is to make 2 projects in one solution.

The first project is a WPF server application. 
This application must send a message to one, or to a group of clients, or to all clients.

The second project is a client application, and the client can communicate only and exclusively with the server. First I want to establish communication between the client and the server. I pointed to a server side that works perfectly in the Console application, but in WPF not work properly.

Problem is:
The server side starts without any problems, but when the client is started, the application trow a error: 
**SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**

Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";

    private string _connection { get; set; }
    public string Connection
    {
        get { return _connection; }
        set
        {
            _connection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

//Constructor    
public ServerChatViewModel()
            {
                StartServer();
            }

    private void StartServer()
            {
                using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
                {
                    Connection = "Server running";
                }
            }

        public class Startup
        {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                app.MapSignalR();
            }
        }

        [HubName("FlexiHub")]
        public class FlexiHub : Hub
        {
            public void HUBSendMessage(string message)
            {
                Clients.All.messageRecieved(message);
            }
        }
```

The problem is on the server side because I made a console application with the specified code and clients are able to connect.

Comment: Also give a look at Azure SignalR Service
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/signalr-service/

Comment: Check the ports if are opened (allowed) on the firewall, on the server.

Comment: Ports is opened on the firewall but still not work :/

Comment: Some antivírus also block some ports / protocols. Did you check that?

Comment: I check that and everything fine. I have a server-side console application with the same code and everything works properly, on the same port. Since this is WPF MVVM problem is probably in some theread, but I still do not know what is the root of the problem.